# New document being created instead of updated

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `onPress` on an edit page - it should update the document when edited and saved.

However, it is currently creating a new document with that data instead.

```
onPressed: () async {

//controllers...

await updateContact(context);
Navigator.pop(context, widget.contact);
}
```

.

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

.

```
 Future updateContact(context) async {
final uid = await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
await db
    .collection('userData')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('Contacts')
    .doc(widget.contact.documentId)
    .set({
  'Name': oneController.text,
  'PhoneNumber': int.tryParse(twoController.text),
  'Location': threeController.text,
  'Rating': int.tryParse(fourController.text),
  'Instagram': fiveController.text,
  'Birthday': int.tryParse(sixController.text),
  'Notes': sevenController.text},
   SetOptions(merge: true));
```

.

```
Contact.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) :
//...
documentId = snapshot.id;
```

I am not sure how to best resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `set()` will override all the data already present in firestore.

and yes, using `update` is the way to go, but keep in mind not to call `.toJson()` on the entire object as update only takes the fields that are needed to be updated.
So if you update with the entire object, it'll create a new one again.

You could pass it like this

```
.update({'name': oneController.text, 'birth': twoContorller.text, 'email': threeController.text});
```

alternatively, you can also use `set(  setOptions: SetOptions(merge:true))` this will update only the fields that have changed in the document.

Comment: Thank you Sameer. Where do I do put the `set(setOptions: SetOptions(merge:true))`?

Comment: @ashf Instead of `update()`,  use `set()` with `SetOptions()` the IDE will autocomplete for you just hit ctrl+space

Comment: `set(SetOptions(merge: true));` is giving `'The argument type 'SetOptions' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: OKay looks like something might have been changed in the version of firebase plugin, 
refer to [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) documentation for more info, I tink its better you go with `update` for now.

Comment: or wait a minute, are you putting SetOptions() before the json? Make sure json is the first argument, and then SetOptions is after it

Comment: Yes the SetOptions is after it. I've just added the new code to the question. That logic creates another document instead of updating

Comment: The important thing to note is, merge only merges if the values are not changed. Instead of or directly using controller values, would recommend using a DTO you'll have more control